# Mat-Table inside a Mat-Table shows extra row for every record Inbox x

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a Mat-Table inside a Mat-Table. The data displayed is correct. However, for every row of the parent row, it shows one extra empty row in the Mat-Table. As I am unable to trace the error, I seek help on this forum. Please help.

The HTML code is as follows.

```html
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="listData" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort multiTemplateDataRows width="100%">

      <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
              The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

      <!-- Tax Code Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="taxCode">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Tax Code </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" align="left"> {{element.taxCode}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Tax Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="taxDescription">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" align="left"> {{element.taxDescription}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Tax Type Code Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="taxTypeCode">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Tax Type Code </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" align="left"> {{element.taxTypeCode}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Edit Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <a mat-button matTooltip="Edit" [routerLink]="['/tax/edit', row.taxCode]" *ngIf="isUserAuthenticated"><mat-icon>create</mat-icon></a>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Delete Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <button mat-button matTooltip="Delete" color="warn" (click)="onDelete(row.taxCode)" *ngIf="isUserAuthenticated"><mat-icon>clear</mat-icon></button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
          <div class="example-element-detail"
              [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'" *ngIf="element.taxVersion.length > 0">

            <table mat-table [dataSource]="element.taxVersion" class="mat-elevation-z8" width="100%">

              <ng-container matColumnDef="taxID">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tax ID </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let elem"> {{elem.taxID}} </td>
              </ng-container>
            
              <ng-container matColumnDef="versionCode">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Version Code </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let elem"> {{elem.versionCode}} </td>
              </ng-container>
            
              <ng-container matColumnDef="versionDate">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Version Date </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let elem"> {{elem.versionDate}} </td>
              </ng-container>
            
              <ng-container matColumnDef="taxRate">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tax Rate </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let elem"> {{elem.taxRate}} </td>
              </ng-container>
            
              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsVersion"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsVersion;"></tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
                          class="example-element-row"
                          [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === row"
                          (click)="expandedElement = row"
      >
      </tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[7, 15, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmBLf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the ng-container if no element.taxVersion, right now it looks like you are only showing the  inside of the ng-container if length is greater than 0 leaving an empty container.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="element.taxVersion.length > 0" matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
```

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong syntax for the *ngIf, the *ngIf you are using on the div should work on the ng-container too.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unfortunate side effect of using a mat-table inside another mat-table. Mat-table will render all mat-rows inside its scope, including the ones in the inner table. You can give your `<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsVersion;"></tr>` row an additional class `class='inner-table-row'` and inspect the extra row to see if this is the issue. Your best bet for fixing this would be to move the inner table into another component and use a selector to render it inside the outer table.